# AngularJS HTML Pages- Setting default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

I am trying to set the default for one of the drop down in the Angular HTML Page. I am using tabs in the Page, when The Tabs are clicked I want to load the default into the page.

```
<div class="col-md-9" ng-cloak ng-controller="ServiceTypeController">
 <md-content>
   <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="selectedIndex">
    <md-tab label="Details">
        <div ng-include="'././Views/Angular/Requests/details.html'"></div>
    </md-tab>

    <md-tab label="Create Request">
        <div ng-include="'././Views/Angular/Requests/createRequest.html'" md-on-select ="clearRequest(requestForm)"></div>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
</md-content>
</div>
```

Hoping on the Create Request is clicked it will call the clearRequest function. Where the clear Request function looks like

```
  $scope.serviceReasons = [
    { id: 1, value: 'ABC' },
    { id: 2, value: 'DEF' }
   ];

$scope.clearRequest = function (form) {
    $scope.request = {
        serviceReason : "ABC",
    };
    form.$setPristine();
    form.$setUntouched();
};
```

And the CreateRequest Page

```
<form name="requestForm"> 
 <div class="form-group col-md-6 md-padding">
   <div class="text-primary">
     <h3>Create Request</h3>
    </div>

      <div>
        <label style="font-size: medium">Service Reason</label>
        <select name="serviceReason" class="form-control" ng-model="request.serviceReason" required>
            <option ng-repeat="serviceReason in serviceReasons">{{ serviceReason.value }}</option>
        </select>
        <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="requestForm.serviceReason.$error"
             ng-if="requestForm.serviceReason.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-padding col-md-6">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger' ng-click="clearRequest(requestForm)">Clear</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="!requestForm.$valid" ng-click="createRequest(requestForm)">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

The clearRequest() function is perfectly working from the clear button in the Create Request page. I thought md-on-select works similar to ng-click what am I missing here

Comment: Maybe you can change `md-on-select` to `ng-init`

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to set selected option to one of available options:

```
  $scope.serviceReasons = [
    { id: 1, value: 'ABC' },
    { id: 2, value: 'DEF' }
   ];

$scope.clearRequest = function (form) {
    $scope.request = $scope.serviceReasons[0];
};
```

It can be another object (another means !==) then you need to specify `track by` expression, usually id is used:

```
$scope.clearRequest = function (form) {
    $scope.request = { id: 1, value: 'ABC' };
};
<select name="serviceReason" class="form-control" ng-model="request.serviceReason"
 required ng-options="s.value for s in serviceReasons track by id">
</select>
```